# How to read/write JSON data between files? (Node.Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs

I am working on a project which requires writing data to a JSON file from one module and calling it from another. However this does not happen, it returns `undefined:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`.

I need to use synchronous functions for this.

Here is a sample file which shows my issue.

Index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {idk} = require('./idk.js');

fs.writeFileSync('output.json', '', 'utf8'); //Clears the file
idk();// calls the module
var result = fs.readFileSync('output.json', 'utf8'); //reads the file
console.log(JSON.parse(result));//outputs a parsed file
```

Sample.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports.sample = function(){

  var a = fs.readFileSync('output.json', 'utf8');//reads the file
  var b = JSON.parse(a);// parses json data

  console.log(b);// expected output {"instances": []}

  b.instances.push('yo'); //pushes to array

  var c = JSON.stringify(b);// stringify

  fs.writeFileSync('output.json', c, 'utf8'); //supposed to write '{"instances": ['yo']}'
}
```

Comment: Please provide the JSON written to `output.json`. This error is typically indicative of invalid JSON.

Comment: There probably isn't anything wrong with your code. As your error says `Unexpected end of JSON input`, this is saying that your initial json file `output.json` is not valid JSON. Either post the file as @BenBeck suggested or look it over for the error that is within the file.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn and @BenBeck, now I realize my mistake, I was clearing the JSON file to be empty instead of writing `{"instances": []}`. Thank you for resolving my issue.